# Is there a way to extract and inject js code for my above the fold components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

Currently, my webpack build only generates 2 files : App.js (~1.2MB) & vendor.js(~213kb). In order to decrease time to first paint I wanted to extract my app shell(all static assets HTML , CSS , JS). In my case it would be my [Material-ui](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui) app Bar with icon menu & list consisting of paper elements. Is there a way so I extract and inline the js code that generates my material-ui components above the fold (before my App.js and vendor.js get evaluated and parsed). Resulting in almost instant load of the app shell.

Comment: This is what "Server-side Rendering" does for you.

Comment: @JeffMcCloud I meant to achieve something like this: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/11/app-she